# Troubles related to socket permission

Tags: spring, websocket, smtp, openshift, gmail-api

I'm currently using JBOSS EAP(Spring Framework) Service. I wrote this to get some help for the troubles that I'm getting.. (related to socket port permission)

- I'm developing smtp function using gmail api. I've followed as the documentation(https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java) says but I gets permission denied. I guess it's because the library(especially LocalServerReceiver class) uses a port randomly from the available ports and the picked(?) port actually not allowed to use in openshift. I want to set the port specifically but there is no method that allows to do this.
  Can anyone help me how to deal this problem or give some information related to this?
  If not, any reference about implementing gmail smtp function would be helpful.. and it would be good if the reference uses  JBOSS EAP(Spring Framework).
- I also have a trouble using serviceWebsocket(socket.io, vertx). I'm not quite sure but it seems like the service(?) don't allow opening a socket (when I try to open a socket, I get an Exception(java.net.SocketException: Permission denied)). I have tried opening it with 80, 8080, 8000, 8443 port but nothing worked.